# matplotlib read data from url: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, matplotlib, typeerror

I'm trying to follow the 'Earthquakes' example from [this tutorial](https://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/teaching/matplotlib/). The code is as follows:

```
import urllib
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

# Significant earthquakes in the last 30 days
url = urllib.request.urlopen("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_month.csv")

# Reading and storage of data
data = url.read()
data = data.split(b'\n')[+1:-1]

E = np.zeros(len(data), dtype=[('position',  float, 2),
                               ('magnitude', float, 1)])

for i in range(len(data)):
    row = data[i].split(',')
    E['position'][i] = float(row[2]),float(row[1])
    E['magnitude'][i] = float(row[4])
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-eed77a8fb64a> in <module>()
     16 
     17 for i in range(len(data)):
---> 18     row = data[i].split(',')
     19     E['position'][i] = float(row[2]),float(row[1])
     20     E['magnitude'][i] = float(row[4])

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I googled similar questions and as far as I understand, it has to do with using Python 3.+ instead of 2.7, but I couldn't figure out how to adjust the code for it to work. Sorry if the question is dumb, I don't understand what I need to do.

I tried with the following but to no avail:

```
if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    from urllib.request import urlopen
else:
    from urllib import urlopen

with urlopen(url) as url:
    data = url.read()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to use `split` you are using `','` instead of `b','`. The point is that `bytes` and `str` need to be explicitly converted into each other using `encode` or `decode`, or you have to be consistently using one or the other.

Comment: Thank you so much, it now works. I am very unfamiliar with all this so please excuse me. Does using `b',' ` convert that comma to bytes? Is there an alternative way to achieve the same (i.e. when reading the data from url)?

Comment: Exactly: `b` in front of the strings decorates the string to be interpreted a `bytes`, similarly to what you do in the line `data = data.split(b'\n')[+1:-1]` for the string `b'\n'`. As an alternative, you could `decode()` the data you get from `url.read()`, e.g. `data = url.read().decode('utf-8')` (or whaterver encoding is appropriate). See also https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=decode#bytes.decode .